# Can an air conditioner rated for 50Hz be used on a grid at 60Hz?

Tags: air-conditioning

My air conditioning unit from Qatar is for 50hertz and I want to move in the Philippines. Can 60hertz power be used?

Comment: Welcome. I fixed up your English a bit. Feel free to revise your post further.

Comment: You might need to post the model number. Does the specification sticker list anything helpful?

Comment: I've run across several bits of electronics that rely on AC frequency resonance to maintain proper functionality. Change that frequency substantially, and you can get quick burnout.  Without talking to the manufacturer, I'd say not worth the trouble, or the risk. Give the unit to a poor cousin or something,

Answer (score 3):

Don't ship an air conditioning unit overseas, for Pete's sake.

Your cash stake in that unit is "what it will cost to buy a comparable one on Craigslist at your destination" minus "what you can sell this one for here".  That number may even be zero or less than zero.

The only way the shipping costs won't *absolutely blow away your cash stake by a factor of ten*, is if you ship your goods by seagoing container.

Even more, the Philippines have a weird dialect of 240V power where neutral basically does not exist.  Taking an older A/C unit, you may find the unit has suffered some insulation failure between neutral and ground; harmless enough in Qatar/Europe but in the Philippines' strange power it spins your electric meter or shocks people who touch it.

To say nothing of the 50/60Hz incompatibility, which is a deal killer all by itself.

Answer (score 2):

**It's not designed for that application**

I think it would cause the motor to run at a higher rpm, possibly generating more heat then it's designed to handle. I don't think the electronics would be effected because they are stepped down to lower voltage and rectified to DC.

You can run something designed for 60hz on 50hz but not the other way around.

**The solution**

Sell your air conditioner and buy a new one when you arrive. You save the shipping costs (also shipping refrigerant may be problematic as it's hazardous) and get a new more efficient air conditioner.

Comment: It would make the motor run faster, almost certainly and the overheating point you make is valid.  Depending on the motor, you can use them interchangeably, but when going from 50 to 60, too hot and too fast are more often a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using a 50Hz unit on 60Hz power runs motors faster. And transformers cooler. Not the issue!
2 big issues is voltages and coolant.
Is this a window unit or whole house unit? Model?
I won't say "go for it !" Without more information.